# Publishing Applications With Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publish

I would like to be able to publish an application and have it so that someone could navigate to a website and download a setup executable. Then when they run that executable it would download and install all the associated applications that work with my application.

Is it possible to have visual studio publish it to do this?

Or do I have to program an custom setup application.

It seems that there are options for this in the publish section of the project properties.

But I can't seem to find out exactly what everything does.

There is an updates button in the publish tab that I would like someone to explain how that works as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ClickOnce will work for you.

> ClickOnce is a Microsoft technology that enables the user to install
>   and run a Windows-based smart client application by clicking a link in
>   a web page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx

Comment: It's the only straight forward way I know with visual studio without any addins or third party libraries. Maybe you can try to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  Windows Installer XML (WiX) Toolset
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html